# Cannot build deb package

Tags: package-management, deb, makefile

I have followed [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=51003&highlight=checkinstall) tutorial on how to make a .deb package from source(tar.gz) and at the final build command `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot`

Help is GREATLY appreciated!I need to fix this issue as fast as possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify; add src/tympanis.ui to POTFILES.in.

Comment: Idid that before and I get another error....

Comment: Try adding to POTFILES.skip?

Comment: It was my mistake..i copy/pasted the .ui file to the /po directory . I edited the POTFILES.in file and it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is pretty clear about what you need to do there. :)

If you run `make check` in your source tree, when building outside of trying to package a .deb, you should get the same error.

Comment: -1 your answer is not even a answer, you just say "its pretty clear" nothing more.

Comment: Read the error message.

Comment: More appropriately, my answer is in the question itself, as you pasted it there; and I wrote that error message, as a maintainer/author of intltool. :)

Comment: I gave you the answer. You pasted it in your your question, so I don't see much point in simply duplicating that in an answer. Giving a bounty for a comment isn't great either, which exactly what you did.

Comment: My point is that either you are having a problem with the clarity of the text in the error (in which case you're complaining about it), or you are asking someone to tell you do exactly what the error told you to do, which is pointless. This isn't the place to file bugs, and I told you to read the error again, and clarified that it had nothing to do with deb packaging, by telling you how to reproduce the error outside of the packaging tree.